# SQL Server error on insert some GUIDs

Tags: sql, sql-server, guid, sql-server-2016

I have a table in SQL Server database that has a `uniqueidentifier` (GUID) column. When I insert some GUIDs into the table, I get an error:

> Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
>   A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded.

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE [TestTable]
(
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL

    CONSTRAINT [PK_AccountDayActivities] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC) 
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO [TestTable] ([Id])
VALUES ('F2AC4012-83A1-E611-942C-D850E6BC46AE')
```

Note: I test it in another database or in another server but it doesn't has error! just in this database it takes error.

Comment: May be a corrupted index - what happens if you drop and re-add the primary key constraint?

Comment: Run `DBCC CHECKDB`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks, it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can use NEWID() for inserting uniqueidentifier
Or you can try this code

DECLARE @myid uniqueidentifier 
SET @myid = 'F2AC4012-83A1-E611-942C-D850E6BC46AE'

INSERT INTO [TestTable] ([Id])
VALUES (@myid)